# Is there a way to create a PEM file using PowerShell and only PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, openssl, encryption

I'm looking for a way to create an AES-128 key in PEM format (Base64 encoded text file) using PowerShell.  All the examples I can find assume the user has OpenSSL installed.  The equivalent OpenSSL command would be:

> > openssl genrsa -aes128 -out mykey.pem 4096

Is there a way to generate the equivalent file using any of the built in PowerShell cmdlets, such as `Export-Certificate` or `New-SelfSignedCertificate` or anything?  Or, as a last resort, a solution involving calling into the .NET Framework?  I'd appreciate any examples.  Thanks!

Comment: Don't know of any built int functionality for this available as a commandlet.  There is almost certainly something you can do with .NET and `System.Security.Cryptography.RSA` but I believe that gets pretty complicated quickly.  Google seems to show a dozen or so third party .NET libraries and powershell modules that might be able to do this.

Comment: I assume you're looking to create a self-signed certificate? Is calling out to certutil.exe ok?

Comment: @MarkHenderson - Sure!  I can use anything a default installation of Windows 10 has..

Comment: @MikeChristensen Well I got excited and then I got stumped. I cannot get the private key to be included in any conversions I do. I think Windows has locked that down very tightly through any windows API calls.

Comment: Yea, I kinda think this has to be done through .NET code..  Or use OpenSSL..

Comment: FireDaemon has precompiled OpenSSL binaries for Windows, which you can copy to a server temporarily and use like a portable version https://kb.firedaemon.com/support/solutions/articles/4000121705